# Joining over 4 tables

Tags: mysql

Here's a fiddle with the schema and a sample query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/573ec4/9

I'm looking to return C.price using I.section and L.level, which are obtained via other joins. When using an inner join with Cost I am left with no result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/573ec4/2

Since cost is a table that maps a section and level to a price, I would like to be able to calculate the price of all the showings in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are joining to the `Cost` table you do not include the proper join conditions:

```
INNER JOIN `cost` `C` 
  ON `I`.`Section` = c.section  -- = c.section is missing
  AND `L`.`level` = c.level;  -- = c.level is missing
```

So your full query will be:

```
SELECT  `F`.`date`,
  `F`.`time`,
  `F`.`tname`,
  `I`.`section`,
  `L`.`level`,
  c.price
FROM `booking_for_schedule` `F`
INNER JOIN `booking_in_seats` `I` 
  on `F`.`tname`=`I`.`tname` 
  AND `F`.`booking_num` = `I`.`booking_num`
INNER JOIN `level` `L` 
  on `F`.`date`=`L`.`date` 
  AND `F`.`time`=`L`.`time` 
  AND `F`.`tname`=`L`.`tname`
INNER JOIN `cost` `C` 
  ON `I`.`Section` = c.section
  AND `L`.`level` = c.level;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/573ec4/20)

Comment: AH! Thank you very much. I guess as my select statement got bigger I lost track of the comparisons.

Comment: @MarcoPietroCirillo You are welcome!  It is easy to miss these sometimes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some clause on the `INNER JOIN cost C` (when you are joining on the `Cost` table).

It should look like this:

```
INNER JOIN `cost` `C` ON `I`.`Section`=`C`.`Section` AND `L`.`level`=`C`.`level`
```

instead of:

```
INNER JOIN `cost` `C` ON `I`.`Section` AND `L`.`level`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to join the columns. the reason why you have no result is because `I.Section AND L.level` will always return false.

```
SELECT  F.date,
        F.time,
        F.tname,
        I.section,
        L.level,
        c.*
FROM    booking_for_schedule F
        INNER JOIN booking_in_seats I 
            ON  F.tname = I.tname AND 
                F.booking_num = I.booking_num
        INNER JOIN level L 
            ON  F.date = L.date AND 
                F.time = L.time AND 
                F.tname = L.tname
        INNER JOIN cost C 
            ON  I.Section = C.Section AND  -- <<== HERE
                L.level = C.level          -- <<== HERE
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/573ec4/18)

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is the problem:

```
INNER JOIN `cost` `C` ON `I`.`Section` AND `L`.`level`
```

It should be this:

```
INNER JOIN `cost` `C` ON `I`.`Section` = `C`.`Section` AND `L`.`level` = `C`.`Level`
```